# ViewController subclasses should have [super viewDidUnload] in each?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have subclassed UIViewController 3 times. Should each one have **[super viewDidUnload]** in it?

Hopefully a simple question, and not too daft! Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    ...
    [super viewDidUnload];  //<<< In all 3 subclasses?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should call `super` in each class.

Note that this method is deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

Answer (score 0):

You should call  [super viewDidUnload] in viewDidUnload method call.

You should read the [ios dev document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (memory management subsection). I am sure it will help you to understand the answer of your question ;)

Comment: I do use Apple's docs, but I usually come away feeling a bit sleepy!

Comment: read only the memory management subsection (under subclassing notes) of the shared link. You will get your answer.

Comment: Thanks subh. singh, I'll make a strong coffee and take a read. :)